# Fetching user's info from FB in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have done FB login from my app in Swift 3. Now, I need to fetch profile picture from Facebook. Plzz any one who could give me the solution in Swift 3 ??

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333951/getting-profile-picture-with-swift-through-facebook-graph-api-return-unsupporte

Comment: you have got any error while fetching picture ?

Comment: No, any error!! It displays all except it displays null for picture... @ Birendra

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
let login = FBSDKLoginManager()

        login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {

                self.view.makeToast("Error")
            }
            else if (result?.isCancelled)! {

                self.view.makeToast("Cancel")
            }
            else {

                if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {

                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,interested_in,gender,birthday,email,age_range,name,picture.width(480).height(480)"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                        print(result)
})
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you plzz solve the way I have done up there ?? I have fetched all other data and only now i need to fetch picture. Thank you in advance @ Keyur Hirani

Comment: may be hear permission problem. replace picture.type(large) to picture.width(480).height(480)